# How to send email with attachment in jenkinsfile (Groovy Script)?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, post-build-event

I want to send email after post build action in jenkins. Hence I have write jenkinsfile as follows. But I need some groovy script for
1. Attachment for zip file
2. Before attaching the file , I need to convert the folder to zip format.

Note: Please don't suggest email plugin procedure & configuration.
I preferred Jenkins file method configuration

```
 pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Testing') {
            steps {
                sh 'chmod +x mvnw'
                sh './mvnw clean verify serenity:aggregate'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        failure {
            script {
                mail (to: 'email@gmail.com',
                        subject: "Job '${env.JOB_NAME}' (${env.BUILD_NUMBER}) failed",
                        body: "Please visit ${env.BUILD_URL} for further information"
                );
                }
            }
         success {
             script {
                mail (to: 'email@gmail.com',
                        subject: "Job '${env.JOB_NAME}' (${env.BUILD_NUMBER}) success.",
                        body: "Please visit ${env.BUILD_URL} for further information.",


                  );
                }
          }      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

you need to use jekins zip utility to create zip file for the folder and then use the emailext plugin to send email with attachment see below example:

```
 pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Testing') {
            steps{
               bat "del test.zip"
               zip zipFile: 'test.zip', archive: false, dir: 'directory pattern as per your structure'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        failure {
            emailext attachmentsPattern: 'test.zip', body: '''${SCRIPT, template="groovy-html.template"}''', 
                    subject: "${env.JOB_NAME} - Build # ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} - Failed", 
                    mimeType: 'text/html',to: "email id"
            }
         success {
               emailext attachmentsPattern: 'test.zip', body: '''${SCRIPT, template="groovy-html.template"}''', 
                    subject: "${env.JOB_NAME} - Build # ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} - Successful", 
                    mimeType: 'text/html',to: "email id"
          }      
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response Amit. Suppose if my test results are present in target folder and I want to zip target.zip. Then what is changes to above code.

Comment: Also please explain about dir in above script

Comment: dir is the directory path pattern to your folder in workspace, which you want to zip e.g. `dir : 'target'`

Comment: Thanks a lot amit. its working fine now. I have one more small question, How to create a variables in Jenkins file and how to use across Jenkins file.

Comment: what will be changes in I just want to send output.text file? do I need to zip it or can I send it without zipping

Comment: I got ERROR: Error accessing files to attach: Expecting Ant GLOB pattern, but saw '/tmp/output.text'