# Jenkins Scripted Pipeline - Is this possible to send a mail attachment

Tags: email, jenkins, attachment

I opened an old ticket without answers :
[How to send attachments through jenkins pipeline using mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51979597/how-to-send-attachments-through-jenkins-pipeline-using-mail)

Do you know if it's possible to send an email attachment with `mail` . I know that it's possible to send it with `emailext` but it's not installed on our Jenkins and the team doesn't want to install it.

Please let me know if it's atleast possible because if it's not, it's a good reason to pressure the IT team in charge of the Jenkins :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: i believe this is only possible in `email-ext` (of the plugins you mention)

Comment: yes that's also what i think, i just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot send attachments with the built-in `mail` steps.

Its parameters are quite limited
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#mail-mail

You would need `email-ext` for this.

e.g. [How to send email with attachment in jenkinsfile (Groovy Script)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54109346/how-to-send-email-with-attachment-in-jenkinsfile-groovy-script)